# Use different filename for npm than "package.json"

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

Is there a way to tell npm from the command line to use a different file than "package.json"?

Edit:

Thank you for your answers. I already checked the docs and hoped there was a workaround or a non-documented way to achieve that. I'll think of something else then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. As described in [the `npm-install` docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html), this is the only syntaxes you can use :

```
npm install (with no args in a package dir)
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name> [--save|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact]
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm i (with any of the previous argument usage)
```

With no args, the command will install `a folder containing a program described by a package.json file`.

Answer (score 5):

Using only client-space tools, it seems pretty straightforward you can't. npm doc is positive about this :

```
A package is: 
    a) a folder containing a program described by a package.json file
    b) a gzipped tarball containing (a) 
    c) a url thatresolves to (b) 
    d) a <name>@<version> that is published on theregistry with (c) 
    e) a <name>@<tag> that points to (d) 
    f) a <name>that has a "latest" tag satisfying (e) 
    g) a git url that, when cloned,results in (a).
[...]
```

> You need to have a package.json file in the root of your project to do
>   much of anything with npm. That is basically the whole interface.

[source : npm doc](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html)

As you can see, they make it really clear a `package.json` is required for anything to work.

You'd have to dig into the code, for a result which would not be reusable. If it's what you want, please make it clear in your question for others to understand why it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've end up with following bash script which I've included in $PATH

```
#!/bin/bash
# npm.sh - script will symlik pkg.json to package.json and execute specified npm commands
#
# usage:
# npm.sh <pkg.json> <npm commands>
#
# example:
# npm.sh some.package.json install
# npm.sh some.other.package.json run build

package_json=$1

if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "${package_json}" ]; then
    echo "Non existing file"
    exit 1
fi


if [ "${package_json}" = "package.json" ]; then
    echo "Cannot link to same file"
    exit 1
fi


if [ -f "package.json" ]; then
   if [ ! -L "package.json" ]; then
     cp "package.json" "package.json.bak"
   fi
fi


ln -fs "${package_json}" package.json
npm ${@:2}
```

Comment: The limit of this solution is that NPM will prune the packages from your main package.json => it works only of all dependencies are listed in each package.json. You cannot for instance isolate "dev" dependencies in a separate package.dev.json, as it will remove the "main" dependencies during install.