# npm install : specify package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I tell npm to use another package.json when running "npm install" ?

All I need is `npm install -f packages-win32.json` Or is there a trick or another approach to achieve the same?

Because not all npm modules are cross-platform and I'd like to use other packages per platform.

Comment: You can install all the dependencies in all the platform, and inside your code and require them based on the platform. Another option, is to install them inside your code like [This Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722576/can-i-specify-optional-module-dependencies-in-npm-package-json). Or to use dev-dependencies.

Comment: I think the cleanest approach would be to publish a package to npm that contains the logic of using one package or the other based on the platform. That said you can just save both package.json files and use a source control hook that renames the correct one based on the platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different filename for npm than "package.json"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991082/use-different-filename-for-npm-than-package-json)

Comment: Looks like duplicated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176082/npm-package-json-os-specific-dependency/26069595

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify a different `package.json` file as the specs are literally only for a file called `package.json`.

If you have some issues with packages that only work on either os try them out with

```
try {
  thing = require('thing');
}
catch( error ) {
  thing = require('other');
}
```

You can also sniff out the os via:

```
const _isWin = /^win/.test( process.platform );
```

Or use `os.platform()` if you don't have to support node <= 5...

Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 1):

The `npm` command doesn't allow specifying a specific package.json file but here's work-around to install specific or all package.json files:

Create `npm-install.sh` file with the source below and run with this command:

`source npm-install.sh`

or:

`bash npm-install.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set +ex;

cp -f package.json temp;
echo "Installing all package-*.json...";

for File in *.json; do
  echo -e "\nFile: $File";
  mv -f $File package.json;
  npm install;
done

cp -f temp package.json;
rm -f temp;
#EOF
```

Comment: no, the original package.json is already duplicated to file named 'temp'